# numpyThonic way for array comparison?

Tags: python, numpy

Considering the code below:

```
>>> initial_array = np.vstack(([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])).T
>>> initial_array
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 1, 11],
       [ 2, 12],
       [ 3, 13],
       [ 4, 14],
       [11, 15],
       [ 6, 16],
       [ 7, 17],
       [ 8, 18],
       [ 9, 19]])

>>> test = np.vstack(([0, 1, 2, 67, 4, 5], [10, 11, 67, 13, 14, 67])).T
>>> test
array([[ 0, 10],
       [ 1, 11],
       [ 2, 67],
       [67, 13],
       [ 4, 14],
       [ 5, 67]])
```

Is there a numpythonic way to compare each line of `initial_array` w.r.t `test` to get the mask as follows?

```
[False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

The idea is to know which lines (pairs) of `initial_array` are contained in `test`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to exploit unique() function.

1. Merge test and initial_array
2. Compute unique rows, inverse mapping form unique rows to original array, and first occurence of given unique row in merged array.
   Function np.unique does all the those jobs.
3. Check which of unique values occures only in initial_array by checking if first occurence happens after first len(test) rows.
4. Use inverse mapping to reconstruct boolean array for last len(inital_array) rows

The code:

```
import numpy as np

initial_array = np.vstack(([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])).T
test = np.vstack(([0, 1, 2, 67, 4, 5], [10, 11, 67, 13, 14, 67])).T

merged = np.vstack((test, initial_array))

_, index, inverse = np.unique(merged, return_index=True, return_inverse=True, axis=0)

mask = index < len(test)

result = mask[inverse[len(test):]]

print(result)
```

The slightly simpler solution makes use of unique() on merged array to assign a unique integer to each unique row. Next, the comparison is done using 1D set operation available in numpy (function in1d())

```
merged = np.vstack((test, initial_array))
_, uniqinv = np.unique(merged, return_inverse=True, axis=0)
result = np.in1d(uniqinv[len(test):], uniqinv[:len(test)])
print(result)
```

The disadvantage of this solution is doing two sorts (unique() and in1d()).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
res = []
# Go through all your array pairs
for ar in initial_array:
    found = False

    # Compare against all other pairs in test 
    for tes in test:
        # Make sure arrays are exactly the same
        if (ar==tes).all():
            res.append(True)
            found = True
            break

    # False if you didn't find a match
    if found:
        continue
    res.append(False)

print(res)
```

```
[False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcasting to do a comparison between all of the pairs in each of the two arrays, then use `np.any` and `np.all` to combine the results into the one-dimensional array you want as the result:

```
result = np.any(np.all(initial_array[:,None] == test[None,:], axis=2), axis=1)
```

Comment: This solution has very bad time and memory complexity. This is O(n_rows^2*row_size) for time and O(n_rows^2) for memory.